# Adding -ever to relative pronouns and adverbs

Tags: relative-pronouns

In one grammar book that I was using, different types of relative pronouns and adverbs were being described. Among those were whoever, whichever, and whatever for the pronouns and wherever, whenever, and however for the adverbs.

I am wondering if there is a special term for these relative parts of speech ending in -ever?

Also, how is their use different from the plain use of relative parts of speech without the -ever?

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word#Forms_with_-ever

Comment: Common names for the -_ever_ series are 'compound' and 'complex'; either is fine. These relative words are used in the 'fused' (aka 'headless') relative construction, e.g. "You can invite who(m) ever you like" / "Ed can go wherever he likes" /  "Whenever I see him, he's smoking" and so on. In the 'fused' construction, the antecedent and the relative word are 'fused' together instead of being expressed separately as in the non-fused relative construction. For example, in "Whoever said that was lying", the meaning is "The person who said that was lying".